# Begginner Java: nextLine Dilema

Tags: java

I've seen a couple of threads that are similar to this question, but had trouble finding the solution to my specific question.

The code I am writing is for a teacher to input a student's name and grades and receive an output of the final letter grade.

The area I am having trouble with is the last name input gets grouped together with the first name input, instead of asking the question by itself.  How do I prompt these to appear as separate questions?

```
import java.util.*;

public class AssignmentTest {

   public static void main (String [] args) {

      Scanner console = new Scanner (System.in);


      int iStudentID = 0; //StudentID
      String sLastName = ""; //Last Name
      String sFirstName = ""; //First Name
      int iAssignmentsScore = 0; //Assignment Input
      int iQuizzesScore = 0; //Quizzes Input
      int iMidtermsScore = 0; //Midterm Input
      int iFinalScore = 0;; //Final Input




      //USER INPUT

      //StudentID Input
      System.out.println("Please enter the StudentID: ");
      iStudentID = console.nextInt() ;


      //Last Name Input
      System.out.println ("Please enter the student's last name: ");
      sLastName = console.nextLine() ;

      //First Name Input
      System.out.println ("Please enter the student's first name: ");
      sFirstName = console.nextLine() ;

      //Assignment Input
      System.out.println ("Please enter the student's assignment score: ");
      iAssignmentsScore = console.nextInt() ;

      //Quiz Input
      System.out.println ("Please enter the student's quiz score: ");
      iQuizzesScore = console.nextInt ();

      //Midterm Input
      System.out.println ("Please enter the student's midterm score: ");
      iMidtermsScore = console.nextInt ();

      //Final Input
      System.out.println ("Please enter the student's final score: ");
      iFinalScore = console.nextInt ();

   }

}
```

Comment: why do not you use next() since is gonna recognize a token ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `sFirstName`  and `lFirstName` , each consist of a word you should use

> **next()**
>
> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner.

Instead of

> **nextLine()**
>
> Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that
>   was skipped.

@madprogrammer has better explanation:

> Actually, the issue is after **iStudentID = console.nextInt() ;** returns,
>   there is still a new line character in the buffer, so that when
>   **sLastName = console.nextLine() ;** is called, it skips of this
>   automatically (returning an empty String) - this is a very common
>   mistake

Comment: Actually, the issue is after `iStudentID = console.nextInt() ;` returns, there is still a new line character in the buffer, so that when `sLastName = console.nextLine() ;` is called, it skips of this automatically (returning an empty `String`) - this is a very common mistake

Comment: @SyoSyo please take a look at madprogrammer explanation as well : )

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
System.out.println ("Please enter the student's last name: ");
sLastName = console.nextLine() ;
console.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be as simple as adding another new line character `\n`. For example

```
System.out.println ("\nPlease enter the student's first name: ");
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use **next()** instead of **nextLine()**